# How to select all records after a certain record within groups in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Given the following table structure

```
Col1, Col2, EventType,  DateTime
```

How can I select the records per grouping of `Col1`, `Col2` that occur after the top record where `EventType = 3` for that particular group of `Col1`, `Col2`.

For example with the following data

```
Col1, Col2, EventType, DateTime
A       B       1      2012-1-1
A       B       3      2011-1-1
A       B       1      2010-1-1
C       D       1      2012-1-1
C       D       2      2011-1-1
C       D       2      2010-1-1
C       D       3      2009-1-1
C       D       2      2008-1-1
C       D       3      2007-1-1
C       D       1      2006-1-1
C       D       2      2005-1-1
```

I want to select

```
Col1, Col2, EventType, DateTime
A       B       1      2012-1-1

C       D       1      2012-1-1
C       D       2      2011-1-1
C       D       2      2010-1-1
```

Comment: your event  1,2 occur always after evvent 3....this case not come in your senario
e       f       3      2012-1-1
e       f       1      2011-1-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the max function over a subquery:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, EventType, DateTime 
FROM theTable A
WHERE DateTime > 

(SELECT  MAX(DateTime)
FROM    theTable SUB
WHERE   EventType = 3
AND SUB.COL1 = A.COL1
AND SUB.COL2 = A.COL2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to solve this using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

1. Partition the rows into groups of `(Col1, Col2)` and rank rows in every group in the ascending order of `DateTime`.

   ```
   Col1  Col2  EventType  DateTime  EventRank
   ----  ----  ---------  --------  ---------
   A     B     1          2012-1-1  3
   A     B     3          2011-1-1  2
   A     B     1          2010-1-1  1
   C     D     1          2012-1-1  8
   C     D     2          2011-1-1  7
   C     D     2          2010-1-1  6
   C     D     3          2009-1-1  5
   C     D     2          2008-1-1  4
   C     D     3          2007-1-1  3
   C     D     1          2006-1-1  2
   C     D     2          2005-1-1  1
   ```
2. Also, partition the rows by `(Col1, Col2, EventType)` and rank them in the *descending* order of `DateTime`.

   ```
   Col1  Col2  EventType  DateTime  EventRank  EventSubRank
   ----  ----  ---------  --------  ---------  ------------
   A     B     1          2012-1-1  3          1
   A     B     3          2011-1-1  2          1
   A     B     1          2010-1-1  1          2
   C     D     1          2012-1-1  8          1
   C     D     2          2011-1-1  7          1
   C     D     2          2010-1-1  6          2
   C     D     3          2009-1-1  5          1
   C     D     2          2008-1-1  4          3
   C     D     3          2007-1-1  3          2
   C     D     1          2006-1-1  2          2
   C     D     2          2005-1-1  1          4
   ```
3. Select a subset where `EventType = 3 AND EventSubRank = 1`.

   ```
   Col1  Col2  EventType  DateTime  EventRank  EventSubRank
   ----  ----  ---------  --------  ---------  ------------
   A     B     3          2011-1-1  2          1
   C     D     3          2009-1-1  5          1
   ```
4. Use it as a filter by joining it back to the ranked row set and selecting rows of the latter whose `EventRank` values are greater than the corresponding ones in the subset.

Here's a complete query:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    EventRank    = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1, Col2            ORDER BY DateTime ASC ),
    EventSubRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, EventType ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
  FROM atable
),
filtered AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM ranked
  WHERE EventType    = 3
    AND EventSubRank = 1
)
SELECT
  r.Col1,
  r.Col2,
  r.EventType,
  r.DateTime
FROM ranked
INNER JOIN filtered f
   ON r.Col1 = f.Col1
  AND r.col2 = f.Col2
  AND r.EventRank > f.EventRank
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Col1, Col2, EventType, DateTime 
From yourtable A, 
(select Col1, Col2 from yourtable  group by Col1, Col2) B 
where A.EventType<3 and A.Col1 =B.Col1 And A.Col2=B.Col2
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the expected result

```
       Select   Col1, Col2, EventType, DateTime  from table where EventType<3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
Select a.* FROm yourtable A JOIN

(SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE EventType=3) b
ON A.Col1=B.Col1
AND A.Col2 = B.Col2
WHERE A.dateTime>B.DateTime
```